# How to find a locally installed npm module which depends on a certain module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

There's an error being thrown in of my node.js projects, and the stack trace doesn't seem to point back to any of the libraries I'm using, is there a simple method of finding out what packages depend on this package in my `node_modules` directory?

Ideally this method doesn't involve manually checking the `package.json` of every module in my `node_modules` directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bit of bash scripting to automate this

```
who_depends_on() {
    local dependency=$1;
    for file in $(ls node_modules); do
        local match=$(grep $dependency "node_modules/$file/package.json");
        if [[ $match ]]; then
            echo "'$file' is dependant in '$dependency'";
        fi
    done
}
```

Put the function wherever you store your shell functions, and then run like so

```
who_depends_on "your-package-here"
```

The main caveat with this package is it'll pick up the package.json package you're looking for as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `npm ls <module-name>`.

Comment: Did you happen to recently get an stack overflow in ember-cli by any chance? Also I tried this when one of the packages in the stack trace I was dealing with (`merge-defaults`, required by ember-cli) & no dice. However lodash did yield similar results

Comment: What NPM version are you using (that might be the difference)?